# How is this manipulation with differrentials justified?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In this post [Solving a separable 2nd order differential equation (can a similar technique be used)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/solving-a-separable-2nd-order-differential-equation-can-a-similar-technique-be) we can see a way to solve the following differential equation: $y''=-\frac{k}{y^2}$. And the author uses the idea of division of derivatives in Leibniz notation and then manipulating with differentials as numbers. My question is, how can such a manipulation be rigorously justified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $y''=f(y)$, you multiply with $y'$ and integrate to
$$
\frac12y'^2=\int f(y) dy
$$ 
applying the usual substitution rules.

---

The second approach uses some implicit function argument.
You can posit that as long as the solution is not constant, you can parametrize it, at least locally, by $y$. In consequence, there is some function $v$ so that $y'=v(y)$. Taking the derivative, $y''=v'(y)y'=v'(y)v(y)$ leading to
$$\int v\,dv=\int f(y)\,dy.$$