# Correct Method for Second Order Separable Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When considering a second order differential equation, say: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 10$$
is it possible to separate and integrate such? Separating the variables results in:
$$d^2y = 10 dx^2$$
and integrating results in:
$$y dy = 10xdx$$and then integrating once again results in:
$$\frac{y^2}{2} = 5x^2$$
Clearly solving for $y$ would yield something which is not the correct answer. I considered the scenario where the integral of $d^2y$ would be $dy$, but if that is the case why is the integral of $10dx^2$ = $10xdx$?

Comment: If $y''=10,$ then $y$ has the form $$5x^2+ax+b.$$

Comment: @Allawonder I understand such, the issue I am having is why separation of variables will yield the incorrect answer.

Comment: It's because you tried integrating a second derivative. We can't treat second derivatives as fractions in any rigorous way.

Comment: The $2$ in $d^2y$ is in a different place from the $2$ in $dx^2$. That's why they react differently to antidifferentiation. They're different!

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/solving-a-separable-2nd-order-differential-equation-can-a-similar-technique-be)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 10$$
$d^2y = 10 dx^2$ is non-sens because $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is not a fraction but is a conventional symbol meaning that the function $y(x)$ is differentiated two times successively.

A more comprehensive writing is :
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=10$$
Then you can separate :
$$d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=10dx$$
Which is integrated as :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=10x+c_1$$
$$dy=(10x+c_1)dx$$
And integrated again :
$$y=5x^2+c_1x+c_2$$

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I appreciate it a lot, thanks! Is there a reasoning why dy/dx can be treated as a separable fraction, however?

Comment: In a few words limited by the size of a comment, one cannot treat rigorously the basic of differential calculus. A key is the notion of infinitesimals conventionally noted $dx$ , $dy$, … which are smaller than any real number ( in absolue value of course).  There are several methods to rigorously relate $dy$ and $dx$ to the notion of derivative of a function $y(x)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus .

Answer (score 0):

I think the "separable" concept does not apply to second order equations. I think you'd have a hard time getting a correct solution of $${d^2y\over dx^2}=y$$ by separation of variables.

Answer (score 0):

The correct difference equation is
$$
y(x+dx)-2y(x)+y(x-dx)=(d^2y)(x)=10(dx)^2
$$
This can be solved as any other difference equation. The left side has as characteristic roots $1$ as a double root, which is in resonance with the constant term on the right side, so you get as solution of the inhomogeneous difference equation
$$
y(x+n\,dx)=A+Bn+Cn^2.
$$
Inserting this for $n=-1,0,1$ gives
\begin{align}
A&=y(x),\\
2B&=y(x+dx)-y(x-dx)=2y'(x)\,dx,\\
2C&=y(x+dx)-2y(x)+y(x-dx)=10(dx)^2,
\end{align}
so that 
$$
y(x+n\,dx)=y(x)+y'(x)\,(n\,dx)+5\,(n\,dx)^2
$$
or
$$
y(x)=y(x_0)+y'(x_0)(x-x_0)+5(x-x_0)^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of

$$
y'y'' = 10 y'
$$

or

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dx}(y')^2 = 10\sqrt{(y')^2}
$$

now separating variables

$$
\frac 12\frac{d\eta}{\sqrt{\eta}} = 10 dx
$$

and after integration

$$
\sqrt \eta = 10 x + c_1 = y'
$$

and finally

$$
y = 5 x^2+c_1 x+ c_2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's proceed appropriately: We have $\mathrm d\mathrm d y=\mathrm{d^2}y=10\mathrm d x^2=(10\mathrm d x)\mathrm d x.$ Integrating gives $\mathrm d y=(10x+a)\mathrm d x.$ Integrating again gives $$y=5x^2+ax+b,$$ as wanted.