# how to find solution of 2nd order differential equations without trial and error? With only the skills learn in Cal I

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

How do we solve a question like this with only the skills in Calculus 1. Or is trial and error our best shot?

I tried separating it to one variable on each side, but ended up with $y \ln y + y + c = \frac {x^2}{2} +c$ and couldn't reduce further to solve for y...

[image]

Comment: Just take the second derivative of each one and see what you get...?

Comment: so... trial and error is the only way?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you mean by "Calculus I", which I don't know. Of course if you know how solve constant-coefficient linear ODEs using the characteristic polynomial, you could do that and see which option doesn't match the form of the general solution.

Comment: I don't think I've learnt ODEs. Could I continue from what I tried? I separated them one variable to each side and then integrated it back to this: $y \ln y + y + c = \frac {x^2}{2} +c$ but can't seem to go on from there

Comment: That's not at all correct! What on earth did you do there? Something similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3339806/1242), or what?

Comment: You cannot separate this DE, it is not first order.

Comment: @HansLundmark, from khan academy, they said at this stage we can treat them as fractions..

Comment: Where? I'm pretty sure they did **not** say that for an ODE like this! For **first-order** separable equations $dy/dx=F(x) \, G(y)$ you can sort of do that, although that explanation is a source of endless confusion and hides that fact that [what you are *really* doing is just using the chain rule backwards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation). But for **second-order** ODEs it doesn't work like that – why would it?

Comment: Have a look at [this unit on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations) instead; the very first item is enough for your case $y''-3y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to solve this **problem** using only Calculus I skills, not how to solve this equation.  The problem does not ask you to solve the equation, it offers several functions and asks which, if any, is not a solution to the equation.  That can be done by differentiating each function and plugging that into the equation.  That is NOT "trial and error"!